# Can a subscription contain an auto-renewing base plan without any offer?

Tags: android, play-billing-library

In Google Billing Library 5.0, a subscription can contain one or more base plans and a single base plan can have multiple offers.
Also, offers can be created only for the auto-renewing base plans (prepaid base plans can’t contain offers).

But it's unclear from the documentation, whether it's possible that a subscription can contain an auto-renewing base plan without any offer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. As the documentation says *"Offers define a discount available to eligible users"*. You use it in case when you'd like to offer the user some discount, free trial or introductory price - so it's optional.

Might be helpful: [Understanding subscriptions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12154973)